# ChromiumのOfficialビルドを行う方法を教えてください

Tags: windows, google-chrome

バージョン: 92.0.4515.131（Official Build） （64 ビット）

のようにChromiumにはOfficial Buildが存在します。いろいろなドキュメントを探してもビルドの方法がわかりませんでした。やりかたを教えください。Windowsです

Comment: これらのページあたりでは？ [Checking out and Building Chromium for Windows](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md), [Windows Build Instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/56.0.2886.1/docs/windows_build_instructions.md), [How to build chromium on Windows](https://github.com/intel/webml-polyfill/wiki/How-to-build-chromium-on-Windows)

Answer (score 1):

[Official Chrome build](https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration#TOC-use_goma-true-goma_dir-home-me-somewhere-goma-Optional-Official-Chrome-build) に書いてあります。

`args.gn` に

```
is_official_build = true
is_chrome_branded = true
is_debug = false
```

Answer (score 0):

求められている「Officialビルド」とは何でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のようにGoogle社によるデジタル署名されたバイナリの生成方法でしょうか？
これはGoogle社にしかビルドできません。第三者によって簡単に作成出来たら、それこそ問題なのでは。

また、[Google Chrome および Chrome OS 追加利用規約](https://www.google.com/intl/ja/chrome/terms/)にあるように、AVC および MPEG-4 のコードを含んでいます。これは、ソース公開されているChromiumには含まれていないと思います。

Comment: 通常のビルドはデベロッパービルドになりますが、何かをすると、にChromiumについての場所にOfficialビルドと書かれます。差はあまりありませんが、試験機能の設定などに差が表れるのでOfficialビルドを使用したいです。[![公式ビルドの画像][1]][1]


  

ビデオコーディックとOfficialビルドはgnコマンドの`gn args out/Default`などを編集すると利用可能になるようです（fetch Chromuiumをした後に古いChromiumにすることはできるのだろうか、、、ただ、--no-historyのフラグを使用していなければできるのかもしれません。）

Comment: @Surapunoyousei さん、そういった(実際は既に判明しているけれども質問には書かなかった)情報はコメントで返すのではなく、更にまだ書かれていない情報があればそれも含めて質問記事を編集して追記してください。